What stops you from use private IPs in Internet?
I know there are some IP addresses ranges called "Private IPs" which are used in private networks and are not supposed to be used in public networks like Internet. I also read another question in this forum where is clearly stated you just can't use them in those types of networks.
Nevertheless I'm still wondering what stops you from do that. Why it's not possible to give a private IP address to a device which you are going to expose on the Internet? Is just that the ISP won't ever give you such a type of IP? Couldn't it be set manually some way?

IP does not have a concept of "public" or "private". An address is an address, although there are various special use addresses defined in RFC's. What makes an address "private" is community agreement not to route them, at least globally.
Just as you can use RFC1918 address blocks however you want within your own network -- even spanning the globe -- so can any other network, including an ISP. Most (if not all) ISPs do use "private" addresses within their own network. It's generally frowned upon to have those blocks exposed to internet facing systems, but from time to time they are. (i.e. you should not be able to traceroute to any of those addresses.)
[Technically, you can do whatever you want with ANY address blocks. Using global addresses internally will just result in those parts of the actual internet being unreachable.]

The companies on the Internet, including any ISPs, have agreed not to route packets using certain address ranges, including the Private IP address ranges.
In any case, a device with any IP address needs to connect to another device in that network. If you simply put a Private address on your device, it will not match the network on the ISP, so you cannot communicate with the ISP. Your device and the ISP router to which it connects must share a network.

Thanks for the answer.
Thus the public network I reach through my gateway won't never be a private network (so using private addresses ranges and a netmask) because the company/ISP just never create networks with private IPs or this is a direct consequence of the agreement not to route packets using private address ranges?

"Thus the public network I reach through my gateway won't never be a private network" Unfortunately, that is not exactly correct. Because the IP address shortage, ISPs are now resorting to using Private and Shared (10.100.64.0/10) addresses in their networks for residential (off-topic here) users and performing a NAT on their routers for those users. Not all do, but more will, saving their public addresses for businesses willing to pay for the privilege.

@ela, see this answer

Ok, I did a quick read at the question and I understood that even passing through my gateway I still could reach a "private" network created by my ISP behind a first NAPT passage?
Therefore, to reach Internet, my packets should do: MY private network -> NAPT -> ISP created "private" network -> NAPT -> Internet.
Is it correct?

Yes. That is an unfortunate situation created by the address shortage.

Ok, got it. Still, generally speaking, I could expect not to find such addressess outsite my private network, right?

Not from the public Internet. Even if your ISP were to try to route a Private address, the next ISP or company to which it connects will drop it. There is nothing in IP itself that distinguishes public or private, only that companies have agreed to not route packets with private addresses (and some others too). To get traffic between private networks across the public internet, you need to use a mitigation like a tunnel/VPN.
